# .htaccess SetHandler error on index

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We use this in our .htaccess file:

```
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
```

This works fine on all files without a php extension, like: search, credits, docs etc. 
Including files with a php extension works fine as well.

However, when using 'index' **without** the php-extension as default file for the directory, the server gives a 403.

Like this: http://domain.com/news/

This does work: http://domain.com/news/index/ - but we don't want that.

How can we set the .htaccess so we can use: http://domain.com/news/ and using just 'index' as the index file for the directory?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: This question is clear, but no answers are added. It seems nobody can answer it. Too bad, but it can happen.

Comment: Did we found a leak in StackOverflow here? :-)